# Am I correctly evaluating the improper integral $\int_9^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^5}} dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_9^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^5}} dx$$

$$u=\sqrt{x^5}\implies u=x^{5/2} \implies x=u^{2/5}\implies dx=\frac{2}{5u^{3/5}}$$

$$\int_{9^{5/2}}^{\infty} \frac{2}{5u^{3/5}u} du$$

$$\int_{9^{5/2}}^{\infty} \frac{2}{5u^{8/5}} du$$

$$\int_{9^{5/2}}^{\infty} \frac{2u^{-8/5}}{5} du$$

$$\left[ \frac{2u^{-3/5}}{-3} \right]_{9^{5/2}}^{\infty}$$

$$=0-\left(-\frac{2\cdot 9^{-3/2}}{-3}\right)$$

**Is this correct?**

**Any faster method suggestions?**

Comment: This is wrong and close to incoherent. What function $f(x)$ when differentiated equals $x^{-5/2}$? That is the indefinite integral or primitive you want in order to calculate the definite integral.

Comment: Using $u$-substitution is a little circuitous.  You have $\int_0^\infty x^{-5/2} dx$, so you should be able to find an indefinite integral immediately

Comment: @SimonS oh $\frac{x^{-5/2+1}}{-5/2+1}$ stupid me....

Comment: Up to you. I probably would.

Comment: @SimonS now since there is an answer already, I can't delete.

Comment: Mark it as correct so the thread is considered 'answered'

Comment: @SimonS i can only in 2 mins :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did works, though you threw in an extra minus sign at the end so your answer came out negative when it should be positive.

But you don't need the substitution, it's way overkill.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^5}} = x^{-5/2}$$
$$\int_9^\infty x^{-5/2} = -\frac{2}{3}x^{-3/2}\big|_9^\infty = 0 - \left(-\frac{2}{3}9^{-3/2}\right) = \frac{2}{81}$$